# Bilinear scalling algorithm weird effects

Tags: javascript, algorithm, image-processing, typescript

I wrote an algorithm to scale image by billinear scalling method but it doesn't work as expected. I really cannot find any bug in my code but it's producing wrong output:

[image]

```
    Process(context: ImageData): ImageData {
        var imageData = context;

        var w = imageData.width;
        var h = imageData.height;

        var small = new Uint32Array((<any>imageData.data).buffer);
        var big = new Uint32Array(small.length * (this.factor * this.factor));

        var w2 = this.factor * imageData.width;
        var h2 = this.factor * imageData.height;

        var x_ratio = ((w) / w2);
        var y_ratio = ((h) / h2);

        for (var i = 0, f = h2; i < f; ++i) {

            var py_a = (i * y_ratio);
            var py = py_a | 0;
            var py_t = py_a - py;

            for (var j = 0, k = w2; j < k; ++j) {
                var px_a = (j * x_ratio);
                var px =  px_a | 0;
                var index = ((py * w) + px) | 0;

                var px_t = px_a - px;

                var fy1 = small[index] + (small[index + 1] - small[index]) * px_t;
                var fy2 = small[index + w] + (small[index + w + 1] - small[index + w]) * px_t;

                var tmp = fy1 + (fy2 - fy1) * py_t;

                big[i * w2 + j] = tmp;
            }
        }

        var ar = new Uint8ClampedArray(big.buffer);
        var newImage = new ImageData(ar, w2, h2);

        return newImage;
    }
```

I'm generally wondering If I can treat each channel together or should I split (at least alpha) it?

Comment: What does the image data represent? What you have would work for a grayscale image where each byte represents the brightness of a pixel. If each byte represent an index in a palette and not a brightness level, that would explain the patterns that you are getting. In that case you would have to translate each value into a brightness level when you read it, and translate it to a palette index when you write it.

Comment: @Guffa it goes into an ImageData, that makes it RGBA pixels

Comment: Off topic: the artefacts on the edges look like values might be overflowing their range (per channel perhaps), but I really like how it looks :)

Answer (score 2):

The channels must be split. All of them. And then interpolated independently of each other.

Otherwise they will interfere in odd ways, for example if you interpolate between pure white and pure black without splitting, assuming the interpolating is very fine-grained (about 2<sup>24</sup> pixels wide), towards the black end you'd get red (the channel in the lowest bits), getting gradually redder until overflowing into a very dark green, then starting again but with slightly more green mixed in, repeating this pattern several times until finally it starts over again but with blue mixed in as well. A more coarse grained interpolation essentially samples that weird rainbow at a regular interval.

Interpolating the channels separately would make all channels increase at the same rate (and without going back to zero periodically) towards the white end, giving a gray gradient, which is expected.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is RGBA values (as indicated by harold), then the corresponding component for the next pixel is not in the next byte, it's four bytes away, and the width of a row is not `w` bytes, but `w * 4` bytes.

That would make the code:

```
Process(context: ImageData): ImageData {
    var imageData = context;

    var w = imageData.width;
    var h = imageData.height;

    var small = new Uint8Array((<any>imageData.data).buffer);
    var big = new Uint8Array(small.length * (this.factor * this.factor));

    var w2 = this.factor * imageData.width;
    var h2 = this.factor * imageData.height;

    var x_ratio = ((w) / w2);
    var y_ratio = ((h) / h2);

    for (var i = 0, f = h2; i < f; ++i) {

        var py_a = (i * y_ratio);
        var py = py_a | 0;
        var py_t = py_a - py;

        for (var j = 0, k = w2 * 4; j < k; ++j) {
            var px_a = (j * x_ratio);
            var px =  px_a | 0;
            var index = ((py * w * 4) + px) | 0;

            var px_t = px_a - px;

            var fy1 = small[index] + (small[index + 4] - small[index]) * px_t;
            var fy2 = small[index + w * 4] + (small[index + w * 4 + 4] - small[index + w * 4]) * px_t;

            var tmp = fy1 + (fy2 - fy1) * py_t;

            big[i * w2 * 4 + j] = tmp;
        }
    }

    var newImage = new ImageData(big, w2, h2);

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Well it's rgba, but packed in the 32bit ints, I apologize if I caused this confusion

Comment: @harold: Right, the code create 32 bit ints from the image data. If it created 8 bit ints instead, it would be easy to work with the planes separately.